# how to deploy asp.net core development application to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core 1.0 application developed in VS2015. I am trying to deploy it to IIS (tried 7.5 on Win 2008R2 and 8 on Win 2012 with the same results). My goal is to deploy as Development, however, I can see that all the links are pulled from `environment name=Production` tag.

Publish wizard gives me a choice of `Debug` and `Release` that apparently come from Configuration manager, and Debug has the default value of `Hosting:Environment=Development`. This all works as expected in IIS Express. I am looking at documentation for [publishing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) and for working with [multiple environments](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) but neither ties Debug/Release with Development/Production/etc and neither explains how to deploy Development to the server.

Should I put Hosting:Environment somewhere on the server site?

Comment: is the folder with your project located on the same machine where IIS is installed?

Comment: @alexxjk - `wwwroot` of IIS server (which is a different box) is mapped to my development machine. But I see that publish process first deploys to `appdata\Local\temp\Publish\<project name>` and then copied on the server. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @leppie - you removed visual studio tag. Are you sure? I think (or hope) that there is a setting in VS that controls how the code is deployed.

Comment: I'd been looking for a solution for your problem and I found no answers. that doesn't mean of course that there is no one but in my case as a workaround I just made my IIS site to point wwwroot folder of my project. if you can have a copy of your project folder (not deploying folder) on your IIS machine you could try the same at least as a temporal solutions..

Comment: Thanks, @alexxjk. There are numerous development in two physical locations; so it makes this a quite clumsy proposition. I think we will just bite a bullet and clean up publishing scripts that make "production" deployment suitable for testing...

Comment: @Felix: You are not coding for VS, you are simply using it. Dont tag the tool. Also, the is probably done in MSBuild and/or Powershell.

Comment: @leppie redundant tag already eaten, NOM NOM NOM!